# Python, Colorama, assign color code to variable

Tags: python, windows, variables, attributes, colorama

I have changed the colors of Python console using the following code:

```
from colorama import init
init()
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
print(Fore.COLORNAME)
```

But I have to set COLORNAME myself, like this:
    print(Fore.RED)

What I'm trying to do is to make COLORNAME as variable, so that I can change from somewhere else, I wanna make it something like this:

```
COLORNAME = 'RED'
print(Fore.COLORNAME)
```

and the test should be printed as RED, but I'm getting this error:
'AnsiCode object has no attribute str'
because this:
    COLORNAME = 'RED'
mean I'm assigning a string to the variable COLORNAME.
Any ideas please? Thank you.

Windows 8, 64bit, Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, the `colorama.Fore` object doesn't have a `COLORNAME` attribute. You can use the string value of `COLORAMA` to get a `Fore` object attribute using [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
COLORNAME = 'RED'
color = getattr(Fore, COLORNAME)
print(color)
```